# in php how do I use preg replace to turn a url into a tinyurl

Tags: php, replace, pcre

I need to convert a string of text containing a long url into the same string but with a tinyurl (using the tinyurl api). eg. convert

```
blah blah blah http://example.com/news/sport blah blah blah
```

into

```
blah blah blah http://tinyurl.com/yaeocnv blah blah blah
```

How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to shorten an arbitrary number of URLs in your text, put the API stuff in a function which takes the long URL and returns the short URL. Then apply this function via PHP's `preg_replace_callback` function to your text. This would look something like this:

```
<?php

function shorten_url($matches) {
    // EDIT: the preg function will supply an array with all submatches
    $long_url = $matches[0];

    // API stuff here...
    $url = "http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=$long_url";
    return file_get_contents($url);
}

$text = 'I have a link to http://www.example.com in this string';

$textWithShortURLs = preg_replace_callback('|http://([a-z0-9?./=%#]{1,500})|i', 'shorten_url', $text);
echo $textWithShortURLs;

?>
```

Don't count on that pattern too much, just wrote it on-the-fly without any testing, maybe someone else can help.
See http://php.net/preg-replace-callback

Comment: thanks I tried that but doesn't work (unless I'm using it wrong) Should echo $textWithShortURLs return the string with the short url?

Comment: That's correct. $textWith... contains your whole text with the altered URLs in it. However, there was another mistake in my script which I've just fixed. Actually, the long URL is in $matches[0], $matches[1] just contains the URL without http://.

Comment: @the-banana-king: I fixed your regex it has a-b instead of a-z

Comment: @TBK: I also updated  your code with the proper bits from mine, and deleted my answer. +1 to you for figuring out what he meant :)

Comment: THANKS! it works perfectly. Just one more question tho...is there a way I can make it so that urls are only shortened if the the string length exceeds 100 characters for example?

Comment: RESOLVED: if (strlen($text)>100){

echo $textWithShortURLs;
} else {

echo $text;
}

Comment: PROBLEM: the code only works when urls start with http. How can I recode to also accept urls like www.example.com?

Comment: SOLVED: created a second preg replace for www and put both into a new functi, THANKS AGAIN for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question of how to do this with preg_replace, you can use the `e` modifyer.

```
function tinyurlify($href) {
 return file_get_contents("http://tinyurl.com/api-create.php?url=$href");
}
$str = preg_replace('/(http:\/\/[^\s]+)/ie', "tinyurlify('$1')", $str);
```