# Replace old URLs in the string to new ones

Tags: php

I have a very long string of a page content, which has incorrect links which I need to replace to new links.

Here's an example. I need the following url, which has a different ID everytime it appears:

`https://oldurl.com/?p=X`
(X = **changing** ID number)

To:

`https://newurl.com?id=Y`

(again, Y = **changing** ID number)

**it means that every new URL not also become "?go", else it has a new ID, unlike the one it changes.**

I could just use str_replace, but the problem is that every link in that string has a changing ID.

Is there any possible way in PHP to "convert" those?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "_but the problem is that every link in that string has a changing ID_" Is that a problem? You'd only replace `https://oldurl.com/?p=`, not the ID

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in php how do I use preg replace to turn a url into a tinyurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435321/in-php-how-do-i-use-preg-replace-to-turn-a-url-into-a-tinyurl)

Comment: it's not the same ID in the new urls.

Comment: But you wont change the id part in the url ... just the id-less part

Comment: "_it's not the same ID in the new url_" You might want to make that clearer in your question, right now `X`/ID is the same in your old and new url. I don't think you can totally automate this unless you create a map of oldIds to newIds. How else is the script supposed to know to change `?p=12` to `?id=113`?

Comment: it could be easy, but once again, a p=1234 could be turned to id=9865 for example. it's not predictable

Comment: @brombeer you right, I edited my question. sorry.

Comment: _very long string of a page content_ if it is html you can use DOMDocument along with `DomXPath` to get more power in your selection methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make this by below statement.

```
$oldId = str_replace("https://oldurl.com/?p=","",$YOUR_URL);
$newId = "XYZ";
$YOUR_URL = str_replace("https://oldurl.com/?p=","https://newurl.com?id=",$YOUR_URL);
$YOUR_URL = str_replace("?id=".$oldId,"?id=".$newId,$YOUR_URL);
```

Comment: That wouldn't change `oldurl.com` to `newurl.com` though

Comment: Thank you please check my edited code might be helpful to you.

Comment: @Shriji Solutions how can I do that if there is lots by lots of URLs with a bunch of IDs which are unpredictable?

Comment: In that case you may required to create or something